# Calculate difference between two columns - matrix table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a data source that can only be downloaded [YTD](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/year-to-date#English). I want to show a comparison difference between them.

My data looks like this:

[image: Data Source Imported on Power BI]

The matrix table I am designing is to look like this. I am trying to add the variance column which is the difference between the columns added on Power BI. Can a DAX resolve this?

[Matrix Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNPyd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is your original dataset with `add column for month` (I am just giving some random value rather based on your value):

[image]

In order to produce the expected `Matrix table`, first you need to create categories, such as `sale, cost, GP` (I only create a sample, but not a complete list)

```
Table 2 = {"Sale", "Cost", "GP"}
```

Next, create a new column for the `Jun` value based on each category:

```
June = IF('Table 2'[Categories]="Sale",CALCULATE(SUM(Vendor[Sale]),
        FILTER(Vendor,Vendor[Header]="Jun")),
            IF('Table 2'[Categories]="Cost",CALCULATE(SUM(Vendor[Cost]),
                FILTER(Vendor,Vendor[Header]="Jun")),
                    IF('Table 2'[Categories]="GP",CALCULATE(SUM(Vendor[GP]),
                        FILTER(Vendor,Vendor[Header]="Jun")),0)))
```

Followed by `July` with the same logic:

```
July = IF('Table 2'[Categories]="Sale",CALCULATE(SUM(Vendor[Sale]),
        FILTER(Vendor,Vendor[Header]="Jul")),
            IF('Table 2'[Categories]="Cost",CALCULATE(SUM(Vendor[Cost]),
                FILTER(Vendor,Vendor[Header]="Jul")),
                    IF('Table 2'[Categories]="GP",CALCULATE(SUM(Vendor[GP]),
                        FILTER(Vendor,Vendor[Header]="Jul")),0)))
```

Then calculate `Delta` based on the new column create:

```
Delta = CALCULATE(SUM('Table 2'[July]),
            FILTER('Table 2','Table 2'[Categories]=EARLIER('Table 2'[Categories]))) -
                CALCULATE(SUM('Table 2'[June]),
                    FILTER('Table 2','Table 2'[Categories]=EARLIER('Table 2'[Categories])))
```

Here is the completed new table (Table 2):

[image]

Finally, you can create the expected `Matrix table` using all the columns from the `Table 2` as follows (the sequence can be solved by index; I won't settle here).

[image]